# One in ten questions go unanswered...can we have a focus on cleaning these up?

Tags: discussion

Out of 9181 questions, it appears 1300 of them are unanswered.

Are there incentives for cleaning these up and having (as close to) zero unanswered questions?

Having few unanswered questions should help boost popularity as users can be confident their questions will be answered and not left in the unknown state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "incentives". You certainly get reputation if you answer and people vote them up. That's pretty much the currency we are dealing with here.

In addition to answering questions it is important that people vote, and that questioners accept good answers (you'd think it was the least they could do, but often they don't bother).

I agree that the lower the number of unanswered questions the better, but the quality of the content is the most important thing.

So we need to provide good answers, and just as importantly vote up the *good* answers to encourage those posting them.

Comment: I agree we should focus on the quality of answers too as much as the coverage of answered questions.